# How long can one wait before they can accept an answer without losing reputation?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I have noticed that I will lose reputation points amounting to 2, if I wait too long to accept an answer.

What is the maximum time I can wait before accepting an answer, but without losing any reputation?

[The SO question in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013226/piping-output-from-get-childitem-to-robocopy/)

Comment: You gain 2 points when you accept an answer, not lose them. There's no time limit on accepting an answer far as I know.

Comment: I think someone might have voted down your question, and you misunderstood that.

Comment: @awerti: I thought someone voting down my question costs me a rep of 5. Anyway, I have just gone through my SO reputation-by-post and found that it was this question [5013226], which I asked on Feb16 and Accepted on Mar6, that I have noticed (on the day of acceptance) the reduction by 2 points. As you have said, someone must have voted down this or one of the other questions. I have provided the link to the question in question, in my edit. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @awerti There is no downvotes on that questions.. If you have enough reputation.. click on the question's vote count.. Its 0/0

Comment: @Mohit: I would still need a lot of reputation to be able to do that. I am at 117 now and Viewing vote counts needs 1000 reputation. Thanks.

Comment: @steeluser Thats what i am telling u.. there is no downvotes.. I have enough reputation and thats y telling u..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What?  That's not how it works.  You can wait as long as you want without losing rep.  When you *do* accept an answer, you gain +2 rep (but not if you accept your own answer).